# solve A=7A+2B+1C, B=2A+6B+2C, C=1A+2B+7C, A+B+C=1

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, partial-fractions, steady-state

The answer is A=B=C= 1/3 I can't seem to finish the logic below and I wonder if there is a faster way that anyone can suggest please.  This is related to steady state probabilities and I know I could use "Doubly Stochastic", but I really need to be able to solve these without shortcuts.

I used;

A=7A+2B+1C

B=2A+6B+2C

C=1A+2B+7C

A+B+C=10A+10B+10C

A=B+C

Then

A=7A+2B+1C

-(C=1A+2B+7C)  =

A-C=6A+0B-6C

-5A=-6C

A=C

Now I have these A+B+C=1 and A=B+C and A=C, but keep going around in circles not able to actually arrive at the solution to the answer "A=B=C= 1/3".

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The answer you quote doesn't satisfy the equations as written - I think you need to explain rather more about what is going on here.

Comment: In your very first approach where you add the three equations together, you get $A+B+C=10A+10B+10C$ which gives you $0=A+B+C$ immediately and says that $A+B+C$ cannot have any other value.

Comment: I appreciate OP's effort in getting the details done right.  I'm expanding my answer in the spirit of answering OP's real question hidden in the context of this question since he has put ([tag:stochastic-processes]) and mentioned that it originates from a "doubly stochastic matrix".

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite
\begin{cases}
A = 7A + 2B + C \\
B = 2A + 6B + 2C \\
C = A + 2B + 7C \\
1 = A + B + C
\end{cases}
as
\begin{cases}
0 = 6A + 2B + C \\
0 = 2A + 5B + 2C \\
0 = A + 2B + 6C \\
1 = A + B + C \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{cases}
Subtract the first from the third equation to get $5C-5A=0$, which gives $A = C$.
\begin{cases}
0 = 7A + 2B \\
0 = 4A + 5B \\
1 = 2A + B \tag2\label2
\end{cases}
From the first two equations in \eqref{2}, it's clear that $A = B = 0$, which *doesn't* satisfy \eqref{2}, so your system is *inconsistent*.

---

Remarks:

We're getting something *wrong* not because of the steps in the question body.  The true reason is that OP has asked the *wrong* question.  More precisely, he has set up a *wrong* linear system of simultaneous equations.

The stochastic matrix is in fact $S=\begin{pmatrix}7/10&2/10&1/10\\2/10&6/10&2/10\\1/10&2/10&7/10\end{pmatrix}$, and he's trying to find an invariant measure $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ so that $pS = p$.  (i.e. a left-eigenvector $p$ of $S$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.)  The "shortcut" is to add up the rows of $S$ and observe that it becomes $(1,1,1)$. (i.e. $(1,1,1)S = (1,1,1)$) This gives $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = 1/3$, which OP wants.

I appreciate OP's effort to translate the problem of "solving for an invariant measure from a doubly stochastic matrix" into "solving for $p$ from $pS = p$ with a given $S$".  The reason is that not everyone is familiar with the jargons in [stochastic-processes](/questions/tagged/stochastic-processes).  From the actually numeric value of $p$, we can see that OP's mistake is a minor one: when he's stripping off the denominator $10$ from the doubly stochastic matrix $S$, he'd forgotten to multiply another side by $10$.  It should be $p(10S)=10p$ instead of $p(10S) = p$.

i.e. We should have
\begin{cases}
10A = 7A + 2B + C \\
10B = 2A + 6B + 2C \\
10C = A + 2B + 7C \\
1 = A + B + C
\end{cases}
instead.  This should give $(A,B,C) = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$.

Making careless mistakes can help understanding things.

Comment: Thank you.  Your work seems to confirm that I can't arrive at the answer I was given of A=b=c=1/3...I will go back to my instructor..maybe there is a mistake here.

Comment: Thank you again, this makes sense now at least.  I will go practice it.  Thank you very much.